# SSD can't be initialized or mounted but CAN be booted from. How to fix?

Tags: boot, usb, ssd, mbr

I have an NVMe SSD that has been initialised, partitioned, and formatted using Ventoy.  After doing this it became inaccesible from both Windows and Linux systems, but I can boot from it (as long as I attach it to the motherboard, not via a USB adapter), so I know it's not bricked.

Windows Device Manager won't allow me to initialise it (attached via USB: only one m.2 slot available), Linux doesn't show it as a device under /dev/sd* or parted.

Are there any other lower-level tools that might make it available for use again?

Comment: What does `lsblk` display (on Linux) ?

Comment: This ^^^ and keep in mind a NVMe drive don't appear as sd*. More info at https://superuser.com/a/1449520/653259 . Also it *should* be obvious Ventoy isn't to be used like that, it's for USB sticks only!

Comment: Try free DiskGenius for Windows. It *might* be possible to remove all partitions (commit at each step), creating just free space, and then create one or more partition. Note that there is a limited number of writes an SSD can perform -- *if* Ventoy tried to zero all bytes, for example, the SSD may no longer be writable.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik  This worked, many thanks.  Diskgenius was able to see the disk structure without any problems, even via the usb bridge.  I deleted all partitions and then it was visible again in Windows Disk Manager.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik  Curious:  Can zeroing all bytes /really/ destroy an SSD?  Seems an enormous security exposure, no?  A dd from /dev/zero is common way to wipe a disk.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thanks for that about sd*, interesting.  Ventoy explicitly states that it /can/ be used on SSDs.  (And an SSD in an external USB enclosure /is/ a USB stick :) )

Comment: @Ian, a single overwriting should do little harm, and there are some protections in the SSD controller (https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/securely-erase-ssd-without-destroying/), but there *are* known issues (https://www.howtogeek.com/165472/6-things-you-shouldnt-do-with-solid-state-drives/, and https://www.laptopmag.com/news/windows-10-update-may-be-damaging-your-ssd-heres-how-to-stop-it)